# Retrieve contacts all connections from linkedin

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Using linked in PHP API , is possible to retrieve the contacts (address) of all my connection 
using PHP API?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how far you got the api working, you can try requests via the LinkedIn REST console: https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console

To get the address of your connections u can use this request url:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(first-name,last-name,main-address)
                                  ^     ^             ^         ^           ^                   
                                  |     |              \_ required fields _/
                                  | your connections
                                  |
                        authenticated user (you)
```

Comment: question is about retrieving connections of the connection